# C#: Calling an abstract class method which is implemented through another abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I am creating a card game in C#.

I have a Abstract class "Card":

```
 public abstract class Card
    {

    }
```

Which is only used to provide a generic parent (I.E: A duke is a card, a captain is also a card)

The following abstract subclasses inherit from Card, and are used to further specify the type of Card (I.E: An Assasin is a targetCard, a duke is a moneycard) each of them contains an abstract method called "Action" with parameters relevant to itself: A MoneyCard has an abstract method which takes as parameters The Player and The ChipStack, A TargetCard has an abstract method which takes as input The Player and a TargetPlayer, etcetera.

```
public abstract class PassiveCard : Card
    {
        public abstract void Action();
    }

    public abstract class DeckInteractionCard : Card
    {
        public abstract void Action(Player player, Deck deck);
    }

    public abstract class MoneyCard : Card
    {
        public abstract void Action(Player player, ChipStack chipStack);
    }

    public abstract class TargetCard : Card
    {
        public abstract void Action(Player player, Player targetPlayer);
    }
```

After that I have the concrete implementations of each type of card; each of them inherits from one of the abstract classes mentioned above which is relevant to itself.

Of course, each card also fully implements the abstract method that it gets from it's parent Abstract-class.

```
class Duke : MoneyCard
    {
        public override void Action(Player player, ChipStack chipStack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                player.TakeChip(chipStack);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Duke";
        }
    }


    class Captain : TargetCard
    {
        //this card gives passive protection: how do we do this
        public override void Action(Player player, Player targetPlayer)
        {
           if (targetPlayer.PlayerChips.Count >= 2)
           {
                targetPlayer.GiveChip(2, player);
           }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Captain";
        }
    }


    class Contessa : PassiveCard
    {
        //this card gives passive protection: how do we do this:
        //give the receiving player the option to bluff, show that he really has a contessa, or deny the other having an assasin
        public override void Action()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Contessa";
        }
    }


    class Ambassador : DeckInteractionCard
    {
        //this card gives passive protection: how do we do this
        public override void Action(Player player, Deck deck)
        {
            //open dialog: which 2 cards would you like to keep?
            //(now, this action just doubles the players hand)
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                player.PlayerHand.HandContent.Add(deck.DrawCard());
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Ambassador";
        }
    }


    class Assassin : TargetCard
    {
        public override void Action(Player player, Player targetPlayer)
        {
            if (player.PlayerChips.Count >= 3 && targetPlayer.FoldedAllCards == false)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    player.PlayerChips.RemoveAt(player.PlayerChips.Count - 1);
                }
                targetPlayer.FoldCard();
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Assassin";
        }
    }
```

Now for my actual problem:

I have a Player class. Each object of class player has a Hand (A hand being a collection of cards.) I want to create a method in the player class that takes as input a generic "Card", and then calls the action method relevant to that specific type of card. Something like this:

```
public void CardAction(Card card)
        {
            card.Action();
        }
```

The above example does not work: The compiler complains that the Abstract class Card has no method called action (which makes sense)

So: How would I create a method that takes as input a generic Card, and calls the SPECIFIC Action() method relevant to the SPECIFIC card that we gave as input?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: well argumented question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `Action` method is too much generalized, however, you can make it work.

Instead of making multiple signatures of your `Action`, make a single one that receives only one parameter `Context`. In this parameter, put all of the stuff that might be required by different implementations of the action.
Here is the example:

```
public class Context
{
    public Player Player;
    public Player TargetPlayer;
    public ChipStack ChipStack;
    ...
}

public abstract class Card
{
    public abstract void Action(Context c);
}

...

public class Duke : MoneyCard
{
    public override void Action(Context c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            c.Player.TakeChip(c.ChipStack);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Duke";
    }
}

public void CardAction(Card card)
{
    var c = new Context { Player = p1, TargetPlayer = p2, ChipStack = chips };
    card.Action(c);
}
```

Comment: This seems like an excellent solution to my problem. It tackles my initial issue, but doesn't get rid of the generic Card class. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, basically you cannot (unless you switch to interface) and should not get rid of the generic base class for the card.
The base class enables you to call `Action` method regardless of the concrete card type - a good example of OOP polymorphism. One interface (method signature) - different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions here: you can either check for each card type and then call the appropriate method:

```
var pCard = card as PassiveCard;
if(pCard != null)
{
    pCard.Action();
    return;
}
var diCard = card as DeckInteractionCard;
if(diCard != null)
{
    diCard.Action(player, deck);
    return;
}
var mCard = card as MoneyCard;
if(mCard != null)
{
    diCard.Action(player, chipStack);
    return;
}
var tCard = card as TargetCard;
if(tCard != null)
{
    tCard.Action(player, targetPlayer);
    return;
}
```

or you can give `Card` class an abstract method that contains all possible parameters:

```
public abstract class Card
{
    public abstract void Action(Player player, Player targetPlayer, Deck deck, ChipStack chipStack);
}
```

then simply implement this method and ignore unnecessary parameters. Or if you don't want this method to be visible (showing only the method with the required parameters), you can make the base class an interface and make an explicit implementation.

```
public abstract class PassiveCard : Card
{
    public abstract void Action();

    public override void Action(Player player, Player targetPlayer, Deck deck, ChipStack chipStack)
    {
        Action();
    }
}

public abstract class DeckInteractionCard : Card
{
    public abstract void Action(Player player, Deck deck);

    public override void Action(Player player, Player targetPlayer, Deck deck, ChipStack chipStack)
    {
        Action(player, deck);
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: The second option of your answer seems to be what I am looking for. How exactly would I ignore the parameters I do not need?

Comment: The second option means every time the OP adds a card with a different signature they need to change everything. It is a profoundly wrong solution. Runtime type checking is also extremely poor design. I appreciate you probably write better code than this and are trying to help the OP plaster over design mistakes, but I don't think these are good suggestions.

Comment: @Nathan What I understood is that those 4 card types aren't going to be extended with new types.